# Can I configure external content to be served publicly in a folder on a subdirectory that is normally internal?

Tags: dns, iis7, windows-server-2008

So I get an email from my boss saying that our VP would really like to use our `subdomain.companyname.com/portal` for a vendor.  Keep in mind that I host "subdomain" now internally and that vendor is first on a different server (of course) and external (past our firewalls).

So before giving the obligatory "no" I would like to hear of any mcgyvering I could do to have a folder point to an external/different server?

Note:  The `subdomain.thomsonreuters.com` is completely internal site and only users who are on intranet and have SSO key are able to see it.  The vendor - `subdomain.companyname.com/portal` - would be on the internet and just require SSO key.

Comment: If I read your question right, this sounds like something a proxy would be used for.

Comment: Hmmm....  correct let me update question so that proxy is out of loop.

Comment: It would be easier to create `portalname.companyname.com`.   I'd present that as an alternative.

Comment: Use a framed redirect.   I'll bet your boss would never know.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - that was my first suggestion but our division is branded by subdomain so then people going to it wouldn't be able to tell my bosses what a great job they did.  The framing... That is a good idea but the frame wouldn't be able to be accessed over the internet and I hope there wouldn't be any SSL browser issues (both would be https).

Comment: Then how about `portalname.subdomain.companyname.com`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - That is what I told my management - a sub sub.  Since they think I can literally make anything work they have asked me to FULLY look into the subfolder option, strongly suggesting the preferred this.  I would hate for one of our MIS guys to say something I didn't think about months earlier.  I already know our MIS guys will mention iframing and I will have to give a 30 min explanation on why that isn't a good idea, and no one will understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you would *have* to let the subdomain be available externally as well as internally.    Presumably this subdomain has sensitive information on it that shouldn't be available externally.  If that is the case, you would have to configure the server not to show the sensitive parts of the subdomain over the external interface.

Once it was available externally as well as internally, then you could use solutions such as:

- Reverse proxy -- Pull in the external data and re-serve it.
- Framed redirect -- Make it appear that the external data is part of the subdomain using HTML frames.

If making the subdomain available externally is *not* an option, I don't see a way of doing it.   As discussed in the comments, a sub-sub-domain might be a viable alternative.